# Identify a character?

Tags: character-identification

This is on a gravestone in Toronto.  I suspect it is the name of a place, but I cannot identify the middle character.  I did a good job (in my opinion) of drawing it in the Chinese writing recognizer on an iPad but nothing resembling it came up.  I used a graphics program to convert the image to black on white, and an OCR that is usually pretty good left the space blank.

What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [兠](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%85%A0) /dōu/

> 古同“兜”。 (same as 兜 in ancient time)

山兠村 /Shān dōu cūn/ - Shandou Village

Note:

兜's pictograph was a helmet

from dictionary: 兜 (n)  "pocket" / "bag"

山兠村 may be a village located in a helmet /pocket shape area in a mountain

[山兜村](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B1%B1%E5%85%9C%E6%9D%91/7385838) is in 福建省 (Fujian Province )

> 山兜村，兜者，环绕之意也，意指该村是在灵源山脉环抱之中，故名山兜

> Shandou Village, Dou means to surround, meaning that village is surrounded by Lingyuan Mountains, therefore, is named  "Shandou" (mountain surrounded)

Comment: Thanks.  That has to be it.  福建省 was also on the stone next to it.